# Socket CAN on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix, can-bus

I am writing a C application that is supposed to access the CAN bus via Socket CAN.
I found this guide [(Linux Kernel CAN)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt) and also looked into the examples found on [this](http://skpang.co.uk/blog/archives/1199) page.

The examples on the second page are kind of working except for that they use blocking calls which is not desired by my application.
The first one would be better, but only using the examples is not working out as well.

In git diff view, I analysed the differences and came across these lines:

```
FD_ZERO(&rdfs);
FD_SET(baseSocket, &rdfs);
if(FD_ISSET(baseSocket, &rdfs))
{
    int idx;

    /* these settings may be modified by recvmsg() */
    iov.iov_len = sizeof(frame);
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(addr);
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(ctrlmsg);
    msg.msg_flags = 0;

    recvmsg(baseSocket, &msg, MSG_DONTWAIT);

    for (cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
         cmsg && (cmsg->cmsg_level == SOL_SOCKET);
         cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(&msg,cmsg)) {
    }
// ... use &frame variable
```

wheras I am trying to use the following code:

```
nbytes = read(baseSocket, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
```

which should be sufficient according to the kernel.org paper.
Could somebody please explain what the stuff around the `recvmsg()` in the upper code is doing? Maybe this will help me understanding why the first one is working and the second is not.

Comment: Have you read the [recvmsg man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvmsg)? The man page is always the first port of call when asking the question "what does standard function XYZ do". If you have read that and do not understand some specific aspects of it then please state those.

Comment: @kaylum I understood the function of recvmsg and of read(...). What I don't get (not even by reading the documentation) is the FD_ZERO, FD_SET and FD_ISSET. I also dont get what the 'iov' is used for.